# MongoDB & FosUserBundle - lack of columns

Tags: mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle

When I load data using `data-fixtures` to my `mongoDB`

```
private function loadAdminUser()
{
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    // Create our user and set details
    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $user->setUsername('username');
    $user->setEmail('email@domain.com');
    $user->setPlainPassword('password');
    //$user->setPassword('3NCRYPT3D-V3R51ON');
    $user->setEnabled(true);
    $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
}
```

or when I use console/terminal for it

```
php app/console fos:user:create adminuser --super-admin
```

Everyhing is ok (no errors while updating).
But when I try to get that data from mongo it only returns me 4 columns:

[image]

while in `FOSUserBudnle` there is about 15(?) default columns... What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it. The problem was because Sonata was extending from `use Sonata\UserBundle\Document\BaseUser as BaseUser` not from `use FOS\UserBundle\Document\User as BaseUser`. I have changed it in `Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Document` and now it is ok